# How to create multiple records from a single textfield in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to have a form field called *text* that allows the user to save each individual paragraph in it's own record. Is this even possible with Rails?

### Details

A user hits the new action, and fills out the field:

```
<%= f.text_area :text %>
```

They enter a few lines to the :text text_area:

```
Line 1 of text.
Line 2 of text.

Line 3 of text.
```

After submitting the form, how do I separate those lines in the **create** action to be two different records (The first containing *Line 1* and *Line 2*, and the second containing *Line 3*)? I know I have to split based on the new lines (**split(/\n\n/)**), but I don't know *when* to do that, or how to code the **create** action to facilitate the entire process...

Thanks,
--Mark

Comment: Why not using a before_save callback in your model?

Comment: I don't understand how that would work. It's not the "splitting the string up" that I can't figure out, it's the actual "saving it in multiple records." So I don't want to do a before_save; I want to do a during_save.

Comment: If I moved it into the model, how do I get the string into the model, split it up into separate records, and then save each record to it's own row in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the (desperately in need of refactoring) answer:

```
@post = Post.new(post_params)
@posts_collection = @post.text.to_s.split(/\r\n\r\n/)

@posts_collection.each do |post|
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  @post.save
end
```

Basically- split up the text field into an array, and then save each item in the collection as a new record.